# Simple way to remove OpenParen SyntaxToken from ArgumentListSyntax?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Say I have this InvocationExpression, `GetDelegate<Func<double,double,double>>("Add")()`,   how would I remove the Open/Close parens which are found in the ArgumentListSyntax?
I'm trying to figure out the Node.ReplaceNodes<>() method, but even with that, I don't know how to replace Nodes with nothing at all.

I was checking out [this bit of sample code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prakashb/archive/2011/12/02/operating-on-specific-kind-of-syntax-nodes.aspx),  and he tore the entire node down to components pieces just to alter it.  Isn't there any easier way to do this? I can't find any sort of  `Node.RemoveNode()` method.

I also was trying to do something like this,  with no success:

```
argNodeMinusParen = argNodeMinusParen.WithArgumentList(argNodeMinusParen .ArgumentList.ReplaceToken(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.OpenParenToken), Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.WhitespaceTrivia)));
```

**Clarifying:**
I'm trying to modify this InvocationExpression thus:

`GetDelegate<Func<double,double,double>>("Add")()`

to

`GetDelegate<Func<double,double,double>>("Add")`

**The problem I'm trying to solve:**

Start with this code.

```
    private void Init()
    {
        StoredMethods.Add("Add", /*new InvocationExpression for identical signature method as controller.Add*/);
        StoredMethods.Add("Mul", /*new InvocationExpression for identical signature method as controller.SubMember.Mul*/);
    }

    private void RandomMethod()
    {
        var result = controller.SubMember.Mul(2, 3);
        var result2 = controller.Add(5, 5);
        var result3 = controller.Add(controller.SubMember.Mul(4, 5), 6);
        var result4 = controller.Subtract(5, controller.Add(1, 1));
    }

    public Dictionary<string, InvocationExpressionSyntax> StoredMethods
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

I want to transform it into this.
Please note this is just semi-pseudo code,  I'm actually doing a bunch of more complex static generic type stuff, this is simplified for clarity.

For each invocation found in the entire project,  if the method name is found in StoredMethods,  replace the invocation with the StoredMethod invocation.
Results should be thus:

```
    private void RandomMethod()
    {
        var result = StoredMethods.GetDelegate("Mul")(2, 3);
        var result2 = StoredMethods.GetDelegate("Add")(5, 5);
        var result3 = StoredMethods.GetDelegate("Add")(StoredMethods.GetDelegate("Mul")(4, 5), 6);
        var result4 = controller.Subtract(5, StoredMethods.GetDelegate("Add")(1, 1));
    }//Notice that Subtract was NOT substituted, because it wasn't in StoredMethods, where Add was replaced in the inner arg
```

My bigger problem is trying to figure out how to deal with nested/composited classes and members. I think recursion could handle multiple MemeberAccess expressions, but I'm having difficultly breaking the problem down to wrap my head around.
Also,  I am using `SyntaxRewriter` to Visit each node, so I'm not sure how to bring the compilationUnit into that

Comment: Can you clarify what you want once the replace is done? Just the last set of parens missing, or the ("Add") stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't think of it in terms of “removing parens”, Roslyn is not about characters, it's about syntax trees. And if you look at your expression as a part of a tree, you will see that it has two relevant properties:

- `Expression`, that represents `GetDelegate<Func<double,double,double>>("Add")` and
- `ArgumentList`, that represents `()`.

So, what you want is that `Expression` (here in the `innerInvocation` variable):

```
var code = "GetDelegate<Func<double,double,double>>(\"Add\")()";
var outerInvocation = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)Syntax.ParseExpression(code);
var innerInvocation = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)outerInvocation.Expression;
```

If the invocation is part of some larger piece of code and you want to remove the parens there, you will need to use `Replace()`:

```
var compilationUnit = …;

// or some other code to locate the invocation
var outerInvocation = compilationUnit.DescendantNodes()
                                     .OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>()
                                     .First();
var innerInvocation = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)outerInvocation.Expression;

var newCompilationUnit = compilationUnit.ReplaceNode(
    outerInvocation, innerInvocation);
```

Comment: I'm going to update my question with a broader overview of the problem I'm trying to solve.